# CSS animation isnt running when scrolled into view in Chrome. Class isn't being added to the element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a CSS keyframe animation activate when the element is scrolled into view by adding the class to the elements i want to animate only when they are scrolled into view. It works as expected in Firefox, but for some reason it's not working in Chrome. Developer tools has shown that the element isn't getting the `start` class added to it even when it's in the view port. Any ideas why this won't work in chrome?

JQuery:

```
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);

    // Get the scroll position of the page.
    var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
    var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    // Get the position of the element on the page.
    var elemTop = Math.round($elem.offset().top);
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {
    var $elem = $('.parent-content-block .slide-in');

    // If the animation has already been started
    if ($elem.hasClass('start')) return;

    if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
        // Start the animation
        $elem.addClass('start');
    }
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function () {
    checkAnimation();
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-in");

  // Intersection observer
  var observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
        entry.target.classList.add("start");
      }
    });
  });

  elements.forEach((el) => {
    observer.observe(el);
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="slide-in slide1" src="img.png">
  <div style="height: 200vh">
    scroll down
  </diV>
  <img class="slide-in slide1" src="img.png">
  <img class="slide-in slide2" src="img.png">
  <!-- other html... -->
</div>
```

Comment: You really should look at using an intersection observer to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented a basic Intersection Observer for you to look over.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".slide-in");

    // Intersection observer
    var observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
            if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
                entry.target.classList.add("animate");
            } else {
                entry.target.classList.remove("animate");
            }
        });
    });

    elements.forEach((el) => {
        observer.observe(el);
    });
});
```

```css
.pre-scroll {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
    min-height: 110vh;
}

.slide-in {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #333333;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    animation: animateInit 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.slide-in.animate {
    animation: animate 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes animate {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-20rem);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0rem);
    }
}

@keyframes animateInit {
  0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(-20rem);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0rem);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slide-in"></div>
  <div class="slide-in"></div>
  <div class="pre-scroll"></div>
  <div class="slide-in"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Definitely what im looking for! And im having troubles implementing it so thanks for posting. I've got exactly what you have but for some reason it's not adding the class to the elements on any browser now

Comment: Can you post the code that you have currently using the Intersection Observer API?

Comment: Sure, added to my OP

Comment: Are you removing all of the jQuery logic? You don't need it with my example. It's vanilla js. I'd also need to see the CSS that you're using to see if there's an error in the animation.

Comment: @jpsweeney94 I created a snippet from your posted code, it correctly adds the class to your elements.

Comment: That script file has only the code you posted. Other areas of the site are using jquery though. Something must be interfering... The css animation works, when i add the class in the console it animates. Problem is it's not adding the `start` class

Comment: Ok, guess i need to dive in and see if something else is messing with it @cloned

Comment: If you get it figured out, I'd appreciate if you marked the question answered so that other people will see this solution to help them in the future. Let us know how it goes! :)

Comment: Ah, i think i know the problem... The elements im observing are hidden off screen/viewport. So the observer never triggers right? Guessing i need to observe the parent container and add the class to the children img

Comment: You can set the scrollRect to observe in the options, but it natively does the root window (which is why it works for me here).

Comment: Hmm ok. All i did was leave 1px of the image visible on the edge of the screen and it worked, thank you both!

Comment: Happy to be of help!

Comment: You can just add the animation to the default state as well if you wanted.

Comment: I've updated my snippet to reflect what you're looking for, I think.

Comment: Sorry deleted comment because at some sizes it does come back on refresh... Will take a look at my responsive css. Thanks again